# Data not send/received properly

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement a TCP server/client using sockets in c. 
I have written the program in such a way that whatever we send in the client is displayed in the server line by line till exit is typed. 
The program works but the data is shown in the server all together at the last. Can anybody please check the code?

TCP SERVER

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char buf[100];
    socklen_t len;
    int k,sock_desc,temp_sock_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in client,server;

    memset(&client,0,sizeof(client));
    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    sock_desc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = 7777;

    k = bind(sock_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
    k = listen(sock_desc,20);
    len = sizeof(client);
    temp_sock_desc = accept(sock_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&len);

    while(1)
        {
        k = recv(temp_sock_desc,buf,100,0);
        if(strcmp(buf,"exit")==0)
            break;

        if(k>0)
            printf("%s",buf);
    }

    close(sock_desc);
    close(temp_sock_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

TCP CLIENT

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char buf[100];
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int sock_desc,k;

    sock_desc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    memset(&client,0,sizeof(client));
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    client.sin_port = 7777;

    k = connect(sock_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&client,sizeof(client));

    while(1)
        {
        gets(buf);
        k = send(sock_desc,buf,100,0);

        if(strcmp(buf,"exit")==0)
            break;
    }

    close(sock_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some more indentation would be nice.

Comment: Under no circumstances should you ever use `gets()`.  Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(1){
    k = recv(temp_sock_desc,buf,100,0);
    if(memcmp(buf,"exit", 4)==0)
        break;
    if(k>0)
        printf("%*.*s", k, k, buf);
}
```

The result of recv() is not a string, so it will not be nul-terminated.
The above "fix" is not entirely correct, but is only intended to point you in the right direction.

Comment: +1 While I waste time with editing question someone's bound to provide an answer

Comment: You could have spent your time looking for duplicates ;-)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be null-terminated? gets(buf) writes 0 at the end of string and send(..., ..., 100) sends out entire buffer including trailing zero.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit too trigger-happy. Did not expect the [f]gets() But there still is the string-overlapping-a-buffer issue lurking.

Comment: @blaze because it doesn't write a null terminator. If there's one already there past the end of the data that recv() provides, it will stay there, that's why he wrote the code that way, but if recv() happened to return sizeof(buf) bytes we would be in trouble, hence his warning.

Comment: @EJP man gets(3): "gets() reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to  by  s  until either a terminating newline or EOF, which it replaces with '\0'". There will be zero in end of line, except for buffer overflow case. And since this buffer is sent entirely, 0 will be sent too.

Comment: @blaze Irrelevant. I referred to 'the result of `recv()`', not `gets()`.

Comment: @wildplasser how exactly does that relate to my answer?

Comment: Most of us don't use gets(), for obvious reasons. The original code will probably work most of the time, _for the wrong reasons_, provided that a final \n is added tot the printf format.

Comment: @EJP recv will put trailing zero (and all garbage after it) to buffer just like send put it to wire. Am I missing something? On receiver side k used just to detect EOF which it will perfectly do.

Comment: Real problems will start when k is between 1 and 4 (this can happen, TCP does _not_ preserve message-boundaries). In such a case, the buffer would not be null terminated (and the next recv() would yield (part of) the rest of the "message", plus maybe part of the next.)

Comment: @blaze I agree, recv() will transfer whatever is in the socket receive buffer up to the length parameter supplied. Your point eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

gets() replaces terminating newline with '\0'. Resulting string is sent to server, which writes it to stdout. Stdout is buffered, so nothing will appear on screen until program terminates or '\n' is printed.

Add '\n' to your printf:

```
if(k>0)
    printf("%s\n",buf);
```